# how to sort cards like diamond, club, spade,heart in actionscript 3.0

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, actionscript, flex3, actionscript-2

I have cards in array and i have button of sort but i dont know how to do that sort like diamond, club, spade,heart cards want to separate from this cards..

```
    var aList:Array =
            [
                {card:Globe.self.realstage.joker_mc, x:605.55, y:195.45},
                {card:Globe.self.realstage.king_mc,  x:323.80, y:298.45},
                {card:Globe.self.realstage.queen_mc, x:45.85, y:213.95},
                {card:Globe.self.realstage.a_mc,     x:605.55, y:195.45},
                {card:Globe.self.realstage.ten_mc,   x:323.80, y:298.45},
                {card:Globe.self.realstage.five_mc,  x:45.85, y:213.95},
                {card:Globe.self.realstage.two_mc,   x:605.55, y:195.45},
                {card:Globe.self.realstage.nine_mc,  x:323.80, y:298.45},
                {card:Globe.self.realstage.four_mc,  x:45.85, y:213.95},
            ];
```

Anyone knows could you please elaborate this one.Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest adding some additional parameter, say "weight":

```
 var aList:Array =
       [
           {card:Globe.self.realstage.joker_mc, x:605.55, y:195.45, weight: 11},
           {card:Globe.self.realstage.king_mc,  x:323.80, y:298.45, weight: 13},
           {card:Globe.self.realstage.queen_mc, x:45.85, y:213.95, weight: 12},
           {card:Globe.self.realstage.a_mc,     x:605.55, y:195.45, weight: 14},
           {card:Globe.self.realstage.ten_mc,   x:323.80, y:298.45, weight: 10},
           {card:Globe.self.realstage.five_mc,  x:45.85, y:213.95, weight: 5},
           {card:Globe.self.realstage.two_mc,   x:605.55, y:195.45, weight: 2},
           {card:Globe.self.realstage.nine_mc,  x:323.80, y:298.45, weight: 9},
           {card:Globe.self.realstage.four_mc,  x:45.85, y:213.95, weight: 4},
       ];
```

and then sort the array based on this weight:

```
// in descending order
aList.sort(function (c1:Object, c2:Object):int
        {
            if (c1.weight > c2.weight) return -1;
            if (c1.weight < c2.weight) return 1;
            return 0;
        });

// in ascending order:
aList.sort(function (c1:Object, c2:Object):int
        {
            if (c1.weight > c2.weight) return 1;
            if (c1.weight < c2.weight) return -1;
            return 0;
        });
```

If you can't change the object (or for some reason you don't want to add weight there) you can create an external helper function:

```
// somewhere 
function getWeight(data: Object):int {
    switch(data.card) {
        case Globe.self.realstage.two_mc:
            return 2;
        case Globe.self.realstage.four_mc:
            return 4;

        ...

        default: return 0;
    }
}

aList.sort(function (c1:Object, c2:Object):int
    {
        if (getWeight(c1) > getWeight(c2)) return 1;
        if (getWeight(c1) < getWeight(c2)) return -1;
        return 0;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add extra parameter like @Nbooo says, and use `Sort` and `SortField` like this:

```
var sortField : SortField = new SortField();
sortField.name = "weight";
sortField.numeric = true;

var sort: Sort = new Sort();
sort.fields = [sortField];

this.aList.sort = sort;
this.aList.refresh();
```

Reference [here](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/08/05/sorting-an-arraycollection-using-the-sortfield-and-sort-classes/).